# returning result or fault to the caller of the function

Tags: c, error-handling

In all of the examples for Error handling in C and several answers on SO, all programs just exit with a status code. I'm not looking for any of that.

Error is part of input and output and a routine can either return result or fault. I want the function to return with proper details of error instead of just abnormal exit or result in case of success.

Following is not a working but I'm looking for something similar, to indicate both result or error in return of the function.

```
struct Error {
    int code;
    char *message;
};

int div(int x, int y) {
    if( y == 0){
        struct Error *error = {0, "Division by zero!"};
        return error;
    } else {
        return x / y;
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("%d", div(4, 2));
    printf("%d", div(4, 0));
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for exceptions? There is no such thing in C. But there is in C++

Comment: BTW how exactly should the program above behave?

Comment: anything that can help avoid program crashes, and function returns error gracefully.

Comment: maybe an idea is to create a struct that has both result and error fields and caller checks them on return.

Comment: Beware of returning a pointer to a struct created on the function's local stack!  It *might* actually appear to "work" on some compilers, but the pointer will be invalid.  If you return a pointer it should point to something on the caller's stack, a global, or something on the heap.

Comment: @cdarke so the struct error should be an input to the function?

Comment: Maybe, but not necessarily, depends on your design.   You could use a global structure (assuming you are single-threaded) and return an `int` indicating that an error has occurred (or not).  The global struct would contain details of the last error to occur.  Normally we avoid globals but in my view it is justified here.  `errno` is an example of a global used in this context.

Comment: Which OS are you running on?  Windows supports Win32 exceptions in C.

Comment: @cdarke it's going to be in a multithreaded environment like a web server, I'm not sure if c runs on a web server whether it creates a separate process or a separate thread, out of context but please comment just in case. for instance I like the answer by lundin but not sure about multhreading. To answer your question it has to be portable, unix, Mac and windows etc.

Comment: ..then provide all your paramters, results, error numbers/messages in a struct whose address is passed in, as already suggested by @App2015.  That is a common approach.  It keeps the inputs, outputs and errors encapsulated in one struct and is amenable to multithreading because it gives the caller control over the struct ownership/lifetime - it might have been signaled in from another thread and may be destined to be signaled off after the call.   It could also contain a semaphore/event that the originator thread is waiting on or it could contain a calback function pointer.

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks. When you say all inputs, outputs and error encapsulated in on, so passing parameters are not thread safe? Please explain more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct Error *error =` -> `struct Error error =`, then make your return type `struct Error`.

But since you have a struct, returning by value isn't usually a good idea. Furthermore, the return value of a mathematical function is likely expected to be the mathematical result. Therefore a better approach than returning an error, would be to use an optional parameter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum
{
  ERR_NONE,
  ERR_DIV_BY_ZERO
} err_code_t;

typedef struct 
{
    err_code_t code;
    const char *message;
} err_t;

int division (int x, int y, err_t* err) 
{
  int result;

  if( y == 0)
  {
    if(err != NULL)
    {
      err->code = ERR_DIV_BY_ZERO;
      err->message = "Division by zero";
    }
    result = 0;
  } 
  else 
  {
    result = x / y;
  }

  return result;
}

void error_handler (const err_t* err)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Error %d: %s", err->code, err->message);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main() 
{
  err_t err;
  int result;

  result = division(4, 2, NULL); // NULL meaning don't give any error information
  printf("%d\n", result);

  result = division(4, 0, &err);
  if(err.code != ERR_NONE)
  {
    error_handler(&err);
  }
  printf("%d\n", result);
}
```

Comment: I liked the implementation, any checks in a multithreaded environment I should be aware of

Comment: @App2015 Not really, the code as such is re-entrant, apart from the implementation of stdio.h. If you wish to pass errors between threads, then that's another story.

Comment: No, I won't be passing errors between threads. The code is going to run on a multithreaded environment like web server to handle multiple incoming concurrent http requests. Just confirming if each user will be served with it's own error or result, like user A won't be getting result or error of user B and vice versa. I'm new to C on the server so just want to be safe.

Comment: I don't like how 'division(x, y, err)' returns 0 when passed a divisor of 0... There's obviously no way around this however unless the return type is changed.

Comment: @App2015 You'll have to declare one "err_t" instance per thread then.

Comment: @LukePurnell It has to be handled through documentation. "In case y is zero, the function will set an error and the returned value should not be used." Providing proper documentation to a function's API is a mandatory part of the programmer's job. As for the value zero, it is better practice than `-1`, since zero is most often the least harmful value to use overall.

Comment: @LukePurnell we always check if error exists before retrieving result value, if error is null then use the value of result otherwise utilize error

Answer (score 1):

For all its flaws, Zed Shaw's 'learn C the hard way' has a nice section on "The C Error Handling Problem" that you may find interesting.

I think one way to tackle this problem is to use debug macros to wrap the global 'errno' value that C provides.

The below 'dbg.h' code is taken from Zed Shaw's book:

dbg.h:

```
#ifndef __dbg_h__
#define __dbg_h__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef NDEBUG
#define debug(M, ...)
#else
#define debug(M, ...) fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG %s:%d: " M "\n",\
        __FILE__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#endif

#define clean_errno() (errno == 0 ? "None" : strerror(errno))

#define log_err(M, ...) fprintf(stderr,\
        "[ERROR] (%s:%d: errno: %s) " M "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__,\
        clean_errno(), ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define log_warn(M, ...) fprintf(stderr,\
        "[WARN] (%s:%d: errno: %s) " M "\n",\
        __FILE__, __LINE__, clean_errno(), ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define log_info(M, ...) fprintf(stderr, "[INFO] (%s:%d) " M "\n",\
        __FILE__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define check(A, M, ...) if(!(A)) {\
    log_err(M, ##__VA_ARGS__); errno=0; goto error; }

#define sentinel(M, ...)  { log_err(M, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
    errno=0; goto error; }

#define check_mem(A) check((A), "Out of memory.")

#define check_debug(A, M, ...) if(!(A)) { debug(M, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
    errno=0; goto error; }

#endif
```

In your code that you want to check you could then do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dbg.h"

int div(int x, int y) {
    check ( y != 0, "Division by zero!");
    return x / y;
error:
    log_err("Div by zero error.");
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d", div(4, 2));
    printf("%d", div(4, 0));
}
```

This way your error is caught and handled by the code in 'dbg.h'.
Now this has one obvious problem in that when div(x, 0) is called: div returns 0. The problem is div() has to return an int and all ints can be produced by some valid combination of div(x, y) for ints x and y.

One solution is to wrap div in another function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dbg.h"

char *div_interface(int x, int y) {
    check ( y != 0, "Division by zero!");
    char *buffer = malloc(100);
    sprintf(buffer, "%d", (x / y));
    return buffer;
error:
    log_err("Div by zero error.");
    char *err_ret= strdup("Div by zero error.");
    return err_ret;
}

int main() {
    char *div_1 = div_interface(4, 2);
    printf("%s\n", div_1);
    free(div_1);
    char *div_2 = div_interface(4, 0);
    printf("%s\n", div_2);
    free(div_2);
}
```

This isn't particularly elegant either though! The caller would then have to do the conversion from char* to an int...

Comment: I don't agree that "on error goto" is good error handling. This code is nothing but obfuscation to me. Allocation and de-allocation should happen at the same place or the design is bad. It is better to use a wrapper function and `return` from the actual function to the wrapper upon error, then leave error handling to the wrapper. Example: `void the_wrapper(args)
{
  char* ptr = malloc(n);
  err_t result = function(ptr, args);
  free(ptr);/* cleanup resources here*/

  if(result == bad) { handle_error(); }
}`. Much cleaner than goto spaghetti à la 1980s BASIC.

Comment: @Lundin Yes I see what you're saying but once you have something like 'dbg.h' and know how it works, it saves you a lot of writing since the whole
    if(result == bad) { handle_error(); } 
function doesn't have to be written every time.

Comment: "Saving keystrokes" is a horrible design rationale. Programming is about writing text. If you wish to avoid code repetition, that can be solved in other ways. In my experience it is an entirely good thing to write out the error check of each function explicitly, since it shows that the programmer has 1) considered error handling in the first place, and 2) which errors they have considered. If you hide this behind abstraction layers, then you risk hiding bugs.

Comment: If you find yourself typing exactly same code over and over again then is this not enough justification to include it in some macro? The macros 'check', 'check_mem' etc are very generic and literally just save you typing out identical code everytime you do a malloc.

Comment: Cluttering up your code with strange macros often causes far more problems than code repetition though. I'd go with the most readable version. `something=func(); if (something == ERROR) { handle_error(something); }` is most likely far more readable to the average C programmer than `MYSTERIOUS_MACRO(something); .... label_out_of_the_blue: ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return structure while function is returning int. But you can return different integers and then handle it something like that.

```
typedef struct Error {
    int code;
    char message[512];
};

int div(int x, int y, Error *err) {
    if( y == 0) {
        err->code = 0;
        strcpy(err->message, "Division by zero!");
        return -1;
    } else {
        return x / y;
    }
}

int main() {

    Error err;
    int retValue = div(4, 2, &err);

    if (retValue < 0)
    {
        printf("Code: %d, Message: %s\n", err->code, err->message);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d\n", retValue);
    }
}
```

I know that sometimes result may be less than zero but its but it's just a rough example.